# Slide two divs simultaneously from left and right on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, slide

Sir,

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>slide demo</title>
  
  <style>
  .leftpanel1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
 position:absolute;
 float:left;
 z-index:100;
 top:0;
 background:red;
  }
  .rightpanel1 {
    width: 695px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
 position:absolute;
 float:right;z-index:100;top:0;background:red;right:0;
  }
  
  .leftpanel2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
 position:absolute;
 float:left;
 z-index:10;top:0;background:green;
  }
  .rightpanel2 {
    width: 695px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
 position:absolute;
 float:right;z-index:10;top:0;background:green;right:0;
  }
  
  .leftpanel3 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
 position:absolute;
 float:left;
 z-index:1;top:0;background:#ececec;
  }
  .rightpanel3 {
    width: 695px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
 position:absolute;
 float:right;z-index:1;top:0;background:#ececec;
 right:0;
  }
  #container{position:absolute;margin:0 auto; width:1000px;height:300px;border:solid 1px red;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;top:100px;}
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Click anywhere to toggle the box.</p>
<a href="#" id="tog1">switch 1,2</a>
<a href="#" id="tog2">switch 3,4</a>
<a href="#" id="tog3">switch 4,5</a>
<div id="container">
 <div id="toggle1" class="leftpanel1">for switch 1</div><div id="toggle2" class="rightpanel1">for switch 2</div>
 <div id="toggle3" class="leftpanel2">for switch 2</div><div id="toggle4" class="rightpanel2">for switch 3</div>
 <div id="toggle5" class="leftpanel3">for switch 3</div><div id="toggle6" class="rightpanel3">for switch 4</div>
</div>
 
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
 $().ready = function() {
    
  $("#tog1").click(function() {
   $( "#toggle1" ).toggle("slide", { direction: "left" });
   $( "#toggle2" ).toggle("slide", { direction: "right" });
  });
  
  $("#tog2").click(function() {
   $( "#toggle3" ).toggle("slide", { direction: "left" });
   $( "#toggle4" ).toggle("slide", { direction: "right" });
  });
  
  $("#tog3").click(function() {
   $( "#toggle5" ).toggle("slide", { direction: "left" });
   $( "#toggle6" ).toggle("slide", { direction: "right" });
  });
}();
});

</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

In above code i have tried to slide 2 divs on the click of each switch. There are 3 switches and each would have 2 sliding divs.

by default **switch 1,2** should get active and **toggle1** & **toggle2** should get slide in. When click on **switch 3,4**, switch 1,2 get inactive their both divs should slide out and **toggle3** & **toggle4** should slide in. If click on **switch 5,6** then previous divs slides out and **toggle5** & **toggle6** should get slidein.

*hope you should do some needful....*

Comment: You have 3 elements with the same `id`, this is not valid HTML. Use `class` instead.

Comment: no sir, i didn't have same id. All id's are different. #tog1, #tog2, #tog3.... all id's are different.

Comment: Ok, my bad, I thought they were the same...

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/yh8pcv9p/

Comment: sir, onload as you see red colored divs are visible, so if i click on last switch i am unable to see the last two divs. Therefore on clicking any other switch other divs should get hide. And get visible only when that switch get clicked.

Comment: Sounds like you want to put two events on one link. Don't know how to fix that. Maybe with if else statement? If 1st and 2nd is not visible, toggle 3rd.

Comment: yes sir, 
#toggle1 & #toggle2 is with switch1,2. 
#toggle3 & #toggle4 is with switch3,4. 
#toggle5 & #toggle6 is with switch5,6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the complete code i have achieved this.....

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>slide demo</title>
  
  <style>
  .leftpanel1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
 position:absolute;
 float:left;
 z-index:100;
 top:0;
 background:red;
  }
  .rightpanel1 {
    width: 695px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
 position:absolute;
 float:right;z-index:100;top:0;background:red;right:0;
  }
  
  .leftpanel2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
 position:absolute;
 float:left;
 z-index:10;top:0;background:green;
  }
  .rightpanel2 {
    width: 695px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
 position:absolute;
 float:right;z-index:10;top:0;background:green;right:0;
  }
  
  .leftpanel3 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
 position:absolute;
 float:left;
 z-index:1;top:0;background:#ececec;
  }
  .rightpanel3 {
    width: 695px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
 position:absolute;
 float:right;z-index:1;top:0;background:#ececec;
 right:0;
  }
  #container{position:absolute;margin:0 auto; width:1000px;height:300px;border:solid 1px red;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;top:100px;}
  
  .active{color:red;}
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
 
<a href="#" id="tog1" class="active">switch 1,2</a>
<a href="#" id="tog2">switch 3,4</a>
<a href="#" id="tog3">switch 4,5</a>
<div id="container">
 <div id="toggle1" class="leftpanel1">for switch 1</div><div id="toggle2" class="rightpanel1">for switch 2</div>
 <div id="toggle3" class="leftpanel2">for switch 2</div><div id="toggle4" class="rightpanel2">for switch 3</div>
 <div id="toggle5" class="leftpanel3">for switch 3</div><div id="toggle6" class="rightpanel3">for switch 4</div>
</div>
 
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
 $().ready = function() {
    
  $("#tog1").click(function() {
   $( "#toggle1" ).toggle("slide", { direction: "left" });
   $( "#toggle2" ).toggle("slide", { direction: "right" });
   
   $('#toggle3').hide();
   $('#toggle4').hide();
   $('#toggle5').hide();
   $('#toggle6').hide();
   
   $("#tog1").addClass("active");
   $("#tog2").removeClass("active");
   $("#tog3").removeClass("active");
  });
  
  $("#tog2").click(function() {
   $( "#toggle3" ).toggle("slide", { direction: "left" });
   $( "#toggle4" ).toggle("slide", { direction: "right" });
   
   $('#toggle1').hide();
   $('#toggle2').hide();
   $('#toggle5').hide();
   $('#toggle6').hide();
   
   $("#tog1").removeClass("active");
   $("#tog2").addClass("active");
   $("#tog3").removeClass("active");
  });
  
  $("#tog3").click(function() {
   $( "#toggle5" ).toggle("slide", { direction: "left" });
   $( "#toggle6" ).toggle("slide", { direction: "right" });
   
   $('#toggle1').hide();
   $('#toggle2').hide();
   $('#toggle3').hide();
   $('#toggle4').hide();
   
   $("#tog1").removeClass("active");
   $("#tog2").removeClass("active");
   $("#tog3").addClass("active");
  });
}();
});

</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you need.

This works for two (or more) divs - one with slider (scroll - master) and one without slider (slave)

```
//the simultaneous movement of sliders
    $("#master").scroll(function(){//the one you scroll
        sliderPos = $("#master").position(); // get the position
        $("#slave").animate({left:sliderPos.left,},0); // animate the second div
    });
```